# how to get value from dictionary swift3

Tags: json, dictionary, swift3

I have `Dictionary` like this, I get value of "OutputResult" but how I get value of "company_id","department" etc..

```
 if let convertedJsonIntoDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary 


 let firstNameValue = convertedJsonIntoDict["OutputResult"] as? String
                print("OutputResult is :\(firstNameValue!)")

{
OutputResult = true;
msg =     {
    "company_id" = 1;
    "department_id" = 6;
    email = "abc@gmail.com";
    "employee_code" = 014;
    "employee_id" = 131;
    "employee_name" = "abc dsc";
    "have_power" = 0;
    ip = "";
    "is_deleted" = 0;
    lastactivity = "";
    status = 1;
};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Swift native `Dictionary` instead of `NSDictionary`, it will give you easy access from `Dictionary`. From your response it is look like `OutputResult` contains `Boolean` value, also your `company_id` and `department_id` is inside another Dictionary `msg` so you try something like below.

```
if let convertedJsonIntoDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any]  {
    if let msg = convertedJsonIntoDict["msg"] as? [String: Any], let company_id = msg["company_id"] as? Int,
       let department_id = msg["department_id"] as? Int {
           //You can same way access other details of employee, email, etc..
           print(company_id)
           print(department_id)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for rply but error in this line
**if let msg = convertedJsonIntoDict["msg"], let company_id = msg["company_id"] as? Int,
let department_id = msg["department_id"] as? Int**
its show type "Any" has no subscript member

Comment: @johny Forgot to add `as? [String: Any]` check the edited answer.

Comment: @johny Welcome mate :)